# Android View internal - CustomView positionning

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I am trying to gain konwledges on View and custom views. I read the series of articles [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), and [there](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-custom-view-tutorial-part-1-combining-existing-views/). Then I decided to take a look on how Google coded some Views.

I retrieved the code for LabelView and I created an app that consists on a RelativLayout in which I add dynamically a (modified) LabelView. I am trying to modify the position of a label overriding **setX**, **setY**. Instead of having *x*, *y* for the upper left side, I want to have *x*, *y* the center of the view. What I did does not work (on the figure below "3" and "30" should have their centers aligned on the same *y*)

[image: CustomLabel views are not centered]

I added some log and that where questions raised.

- Why are measureHeight and measureWidth called several time?
- Why are getWidht, getHeight, getRight and getBottom returning 0?

Below the log (I removed what was not relevant):

```
... I/MainActivity: customLabel.width = 0
... I/MainActivity: customLabel.height = 0
... I/MainActivity: customLabel.getRight = 0
... I/MainActivity: customLabel.getBottom = 0
... I/MainActivity: customLabel2.width = 0
... I/MainActivity: customLabel2.height = 0
... I/MainActivity: customLabel2.getRight = 0
... I/MainActivity: customLabel2.getBottom = 0
...
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureWidth: result = 96
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureHeight: result = 99
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureWidth: result = 33
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureHeight: result = 61
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureWidth: result = 96
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureHeight: result = 99
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureWidth: result = 33
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureHeight: result = 61
...
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureWidth: result = 96
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureHeight: result = 99
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureWidth: result = 33
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureHeight: result = 61
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureWidth: result = 96
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureHeight: result = 99
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureWidth: result = 33
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureHeight: result = 61
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureWidth: result = 96
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureHeight: result = 99
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureWidth: result = 33
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureHeight: result = 61
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureWidth: result = 96
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl2) measureHeight: result = 99
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureWidth: result = 33
... I/CustomLabelView: (lbl1) measureHeight: result = 61
```

Below MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        CustomLabelView customLabel = new CustomLabelView(this, "lbl1");
        customLabel.setText("3");
        customLabel.setX(150);
        customLabel.setY(200);
        container.addView(customLabel);

        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.width = " + customLabel.getWidth());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.height = " + customLabel.getHeight());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.getRight = " + customLabel.getRight());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.getBottom = " + customLabel.getBottom());

        CustomLabelView customLabel2 = new CustomLabelView(this, "lbl2");
        customLabel2.setText("66");
        customLabel2.setX(450);
        customLabel2.setY(200);
        customLabel2.setTextSize(80);
        container.addView(customLabel2);

        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel2.width = " + customLabel2.getWidth());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel2.height = " + customLabel2.getHeight());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel2.getRight = " + customLabel2.getRight());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel2.getBottom = " + customLabel2.getBottom());
    }
}
```

Below the LabelView

```
/*
 * based on android-21/legacy/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.java
 */
public class CustomLabelView extends View {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private String mText;
    private int mAscent;

    //tag to identify instance in log
    private String mTag;

    /**
     * Constructor.  This version is only needed if you will be instantiating
     * the object manually (not from a layout XML file).
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public CustomLabelView(Context context, String tag) {
        super(context);
        initLabelView();
        mTag = tag;
    }


    private final void initLabelView() {
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        // Must manually scale the desired text size to match screen density
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        mTextPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the text to display in this label
     *
     * @param text The text to display. This will be drawn as one line.
     */
    public void setText(String text) {
        mText = text;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the text size for this label
     *
     * @param size Font size
     */
    public void setTextSize(int size) {
        // This text size has been pre-scaled by the getDimensionPixelOffset method
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(size);
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the text color for this label.
     *
     * @param color ARGB value for the text
     */
    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        mTextPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @see android.view.View#measure(int, int)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec),
                measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    /**
     * Determines the width of this view
     *
     * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
     * @return The width of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
     */
    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text
            result = (int) mTextPaint.measureText(mText) + getPaddingLeft()
                    + getPaddingRight();
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "(" + mTag + ") measureWidth: result = " + result);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Determines the height of this view
     *
     * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
     * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
     */
    private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        mAscent = (int) mTextPaint.ascent();
        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
            result = (int) (-mAscent + mTextPaint.descent()) + getPaddingTop()
                    + getPaddingBottom();
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by measureSpec
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "(" + mTag + ") measureHeight: result = " + result);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Render the text
     *
     * @see android.view.View#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText(mText, getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop() - mAscent, mTextPaint);
    }


    @Override
    public void setX(float x) {
        float x_center = x + getWidth() / 2;
        super.setX(x_center);

        super.setX(x_center);
    }

    @Override
    public void setY(float y) {
        float y_center = y - getHeight() / 2;
        super.setY(y_center);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are `measureHeight` and `measureWidth` called several time?

`measureHeight` and `measureWidth` calls are a result of `onMeasure` callback.

This one is called "*to determine the size requirements for this view and all of its children*" (read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int))). Which basically means that when a `View` or a `Layout` that this `View` is placed in, needs to know what size requirements this `View` has, it causes `onMeasure` to be called.

It's important that **it causes** `onMeasure` to be called. It doesn't call it directly. You should never call `onMeasure` yourself. The easiest way to explain how can you cause it to be called is [this `View` lifecycle diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846243/1993204). A call to `requestLayout` on a `View` will cause it `onMeasure` to be called. See that your `CustomLabelView` also calls its `requestLayout` in some methods.

There's no really a way to determine the exact number of the `onMeasure` calls, because it can vary depending on the type of `Layout` you're using, your `View` behavior and other `Views'` in the hierarchy.

---

> Why are `getWidth`, `getHeight`, `getRight` and `getBottom` returning 0?

You're trying to call them in `onCreate` of your `Activity`. That means that your `Activity` is just being created and there's nothing that already has been drawn on screen. In other words a "layout pass" has not yet been performed. Which basically means that your `CustomLabelView` has not yet been drawn. If it hasn't been drawn it has no dimensions (thats why all parameters are 0).

If you tried putting the following code in your `onCreate` you would probably get non-0 values (after 2 seconds):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.width = " + customLabel.getWidth());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.height = " + customLabel.getHeight());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.getRight = " + customLabel.getRight());
        Log.i(TAG, "customLabel.getBottom = " + customLabel.getBottom());
    }

}, 2000);
```

Remember to mark your `customLabel` as `final`.

Comment: Thanks @Bartek! Your answer to the first question is confirmed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA) at 12'50, it is said "Viewgroups will call Measure on eacf one of thier child views"