# Using weight on RecyclerView the items width starts behaving weird

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Whats wrong with the next layouts?

I pretend to include a `RecyclerView` inside a `DialogFragment` to list Checkboxes and handle the check.

Issues:

1. Item text should fill the content of the screen.
2. On scroll the items arrange to the right position.

dialog.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_large">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/degrees_picker"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/degreesProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/degreesRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:listitem="@layout/degrees_item" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/degreesCancelButton"
      style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/cancel" />

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/degreesOkButton"
      style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/ok" />

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

degrees_item.xml (if this just have a CheckBox same thing happens):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/degreesItemTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:text="Degree tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal tal" />

  <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/degreesItemCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

adapter:

```
class DegreesAdapter(val preselectedItems: List<Degree>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DegreesAdapter.ViewHolder>(), SubtopicsItemListener {
  var items = listOf<Degree>()
    set(values) {
      field = values.map { CheckableDegree(it, checked = preselectedItems?.contains(it) == true) }
      notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

  val selectedItems get() = items.filter { (it as? CheckableDegree)?.checked == true }

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
    val contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.degrees_item, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(contactView, this)
  }

  override fun getItemCount() = items.size

  override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return items[position].id.toLong()
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    val degree = items[position]

    if (degree is CheckableDegree) {
      holder?.itemView?.degreesItemCheck?.isChecked = degree.checked
    }

    holder?.itemView?.degreesItemTextView?.text = degree.description
  }

  override fun onItemCheck(position: Int, checked: Boolean) {
    (items[position] as? CheckableDegree)?.checked = checked
  }

  class ViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: SubtopicsItemListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
      itemView.degreesItemCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        listener.onItemCheck(layoutPosition, isChecked)
      }
    }
  }
}

interface SubtopicsItemListener {
  fun onItemCheck(position: Int, checked: Boolean)
}

class CheckableDegree(degree: Degree, var checked: Boolean = false)
  : Degree(degree.id, degree.description), Parcelable {
  companion object {
    @JvmField val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<CheckableDegree> = object : Parcelable.Creator<CheckableDegree> {
      override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): CheckableDegree = CheckableDegree(source)
      override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<CheckableDegree?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
  }

  constructor(source: Parcel)
      : this(source.readParcelable<Degree>(Degree::class.java.classLoader),
      1 == source.readInt())

  override fun describeContents() = 0

  override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags)
    dest.writeInt((if (checked) 1 else 0))
  }
}
```

DegreesDialogFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.medanswers.R
import com.medanswers.api.error.ApiError
import com.medanswers.api.repositories.user.Degree
import com.medanswers.base.MyActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.degrees_dialog.*
import javax.inject.Inject

/**
 * Show the lists of subtopics
 */
class DegreesDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), DegreesDialogContract.View {

  val listener: Listener?
    get() = (activity as? Listener) ?: (targetFragment as? Listener)

  @Inject lateinit var presenter: DegreesDialogContract.Presenter

  companion object {
    val extrasPreselectedItems = "preselected_items"

    fun newInstance(preselectedItems: List<Degree>?): DegreesDialogFragment {
      val frag = DegreesDialogFragment()
      frag.arguments = Bundle().apply {
        preselectedItems?.let { putParcelableArray(extrasPreselectedItems, it.toTypedArray()) }
      }
      return frag
    }
  }

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, state: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.degrees_dialog, container)
  }

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (activity as MyActivity).activityComponent.inject(this)

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    val preselectedItems =
        (arguments.getParcelableArray(extrasPreselectedItems) as? Array<Degree>)?.toList()

    // calls initViews(preselectedItems)
    presenter.attach(this, preselectedItems)
  }

  override fun initViews(preselectedItems: List<Degree>?) {
    degreesRecyclerView.apply {
      layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
      adapter = DegreesAdapter(preselectedItems)
    }

    degreesOkButton.setOnClickListener {
      (degreesRecyclerView?.adapter as? DegreesAdapter)?.selectedItems?.let {
        listener?.onDegreesDialogOkClick(it)
        dismiss()
      }
    }

    degreesCancelButton.setOnClickListener { this@DegreesDialogFragment.dismiss() }
  }

  override fun showItems(degrees: List<Degree>) {
    (degreesRecyclerView?.adapter as? DegreesAdapter)?.items = degrees
  }

  override fun showProgress() {
    degreesProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }

  override fun dismissProgress() {
    degreesProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
  }

  override fun close(apiError: ApiError?) {
    apiError?.let { listener?.onDegreesDialogError(it) }
    dismiss()
  }

  interface Listener {
    fun onDegreesDialogOkClick(degrees: List<Degree>)
    fun onDegreesDialogError(apiError: ApiError)
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show your ViewHolder, please. Also, you write: `tools:listitem="@layout/degrees_item"`, but your item is `item.xml`. Haven't you mixed up when created an adapter?

Comment: @CoolMind I added the adapter, yeah, that tools is just for the preview, should not interfere with the real one

Comment: In order to understand how a width can vary, I usually make different background colors for elements (degrees_item.xml). For instance, you can change a LinearLayout background to green.

Comment: May be you should use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` in degrees_item.xml, having check box on right side.

Comment: @chandil03 same results if there are just a CheckBox in the item.

Comment: @Caipivara when are you calling `showItem()` method of DegreeDialogFragment?

Comment: @Caipivara Ok got it, I think recycler view is filling item when Dialog does not have proper width(during creation:may be). Can you try calling `presenter.attach(this, preselectedItems)` statement in `degreesRecyclerView.post(){}`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your `DialogFragment` width from code like below:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    p.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    p.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(p);
```

You can take a look at my [EasyFilePickerDialog](https://github.com/kingfisherphuoc/EasyFilePickerDialog), and check the file `FilePickerDialogFragment.java` for more detail.

Comment: But the issue is not the Dialog width but the item width. The items appears with width 30, and on scroll they move to width 100 (to say any example)

Comment: Looks like is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027193/recyclerview-item-layout-weight-sizes-not-updating

Comment: @Caipivara, if a width grows, you should limit it by maximum width. I mean, you should fix a dialog's width.

Comment: @CoolMind the width should not grow, should be static, but If I put the RecyclerView height to `200dp` or other fixed the issue dont happen, looks like the weight is messing with something.

Comment: @Caipivara, width to 200dp? You can also use CheckedTextView, but be careful for multiline text.

Comment: @CoolMind `height` to `200dp` on `RecyclerView` and then no issues with items width

Comment: @Caipivara, I usually change background color of items to understand how they are positioned in a layout (and their sizes). Probably a layout_weight=1 is applied to a width, not height (in the first layout). You can also set width=match_parent in all elements of the first layout. And maybe try to wrap RecyclerView inside a FrameLayout. Or instead of vertical LinearLayout use RelativeLayout.