# invalidate() after requestLayout()?

Tags: android

In my custom Android view, I will at some point call `requestLayout()` after I've changed my layout parameters. I'm overriding `onDraw(...)` so I also need to make sure `invalidate()` is called.

However, is it necessary to call `invalidate()` after `requestLayout()`?

Say that I don't, and I trust Android to do it for me after `requestLayout()`. It may be that what I've changed in my layout parameters *changed nothing* at all. Will Android detect this and avoid calling `invalidate()` in this edge case, or am I guaranteed that `invalidate()` will be called no matter what?

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [Usage of forceLayout(), requestLayout() and invalidate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856180/usage-of-forcelayout-requestlayout-and-invalidate). I am specifically asking if there is some exempt in the Android code, e.g. `if (newWidth == oldWidth && newHeight == oldHeight) return; // no need to invalidate?` I would still like to invalidate even if my layout parameters did not change. In other words, does Android docs somewhere **guarantee** that invalidation will occur?

Comment: I think this is enough - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856180/usage-of-forcelayout-requestlayout-and-invalidate/13858255

Comment: You can check if `isDirty` and then decide wheter to call `invalidate` or not. I believe `invalidate` don't check for anything.

Comment: [please refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846243/8873646) think it will helpful for you..!