# how to get view in android searchview OnClose listener

Tags: android

```
searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchicon);
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.getLayoutParams().width = 1800;
        }
    });
   searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onClose() {

           return false;
       }
   });
```

I want to decrease the width of `searchview` in `OnCloseListener` how do I get the view for that?

Comment: Why can't you just use `searchView`?

Comment: `final View searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchicon);` and use it in `onClose`,

Comment: @EasyJoinDev that worked .. thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Once a layout has been drawn the to alter the dimension and shape, you have to call `requestLayout()`

so use

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.getLayoutParams().width = 1800;
            v.invalidate(); // for redrawing 
            v.requestLayout(); // for dimension change 
        }
    });
```

For enclose use

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onClose() {
           searchView.requestLayout(); // make sure to declare search view outside oncreate or use local final variable
           // or this //findViewById(R.id.searchicon).requestLayout(); // for dimension change 
           return false;
       }
   });
```

[**Reference: Usage of forceLayout(), requestLayout() and invalidate()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856180/usage-of-forcelayout-requestlayout-and-invalidate)

Comment: yeah.. but how do  I do that in onClose() method

Comment: you can use `searchView.requestLayout()`?