# How can I recreate a created view from xml file?

Tags: android

Imagine I have defined an ImageButton in xml file,
I set up it and see the ImageButton on the mobile screen

Now, I want to remove it and then recreate it in the same place but this time with new settings

I can simply do such actions when I create an ImageButton in the code
Simply I can remove the view and add the new one instead

My problem is with the ImageButton inside the xml file
When I remove it then it is removed but I can't recreate it there

Comment: Then Try Visibility GONE or INVISIBLE and again use Visibility VISIBLE with new settings.

Comment: the point is not the visibility

Answer (score 1):

You can find your view by id and save it somewhere. When you want to remove it just call `ViewGroup.removeView(imageButton)` on corresponding container. To add it back use `ViewGroup.addView(imageButton)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1) Don't embed the button in your layout file. Generate the button on the fly and add it to your view.

Example:

```
fun createButton(context:Context):Button{
        val btn = Button(context)
        btn.text = "Magic"
        btn.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked me!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        return btn
    }
```

Where you want to add the button:

```
    val parent = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.parent)
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
        val btn = createButton(this)
        parent.addView(btn)
    }

btnRemove.setOnClickListener{
            parent.removeViewAt(0)
        }
```

2) Second approach, if you want to have a layout file, is create a custom layout with the button like this:

**button_layout.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Magic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity, have a parent layout (any layout of your choice) :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="354dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.254"/>
```

I have used linear layout for this example.

Now in the activity, inflate the custom layout and add it your view :

```
val parent = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.parent)
btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
    val btnView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_layout, null)

    btnView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnTest).text = "Some other text"

    val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    parent.addView(btnView, lp)
}


btnRemove.setOnClickListener{
    parent.removeViewAt(0)
}
```

In the above example, I have two buttons, add and remove which adds the custom layout & removes it respectively.

The advantage of this is, after inflating it, based on condition, you can do like:

```
btnView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnTest).text = "Some other text"
```

and change only the part you need to change (eg. text/image) and keep the rest of the styles same.

This holds true for any button (normal or image button).

Hope this example helps, if you have any other query, do tell.

Regards

Priyabrata

Answer (score 0):

You can call view.parent.requestLayout() or view.parent.invalidate() after apply your changes to redraw his parent with the new child view settings.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846243/5941456) reference to see the deferances between those two methods