# How to get EditText width dynamically and set it to a recyclerView width

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have an edittext and its width is set to wrap-content.I also have an recycler view and its width is set to wrap-content. i want to make recycler view width to be equals to edit text width programmatically.I used below code but its not working.width returns from getMeasuredWidth() is not equal to edittext width.

```
    editText= findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.measure(0, 0);
    testRecyclerView= findViewById(R.id.employee_recycler_view);
    testRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams =  testRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width =  editText.getMeasuredWidth();
    testRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should end with `<View>.requestLayout()` to refresh with a new size (currently `employeeRecyclerView`).

Also views are not correctly measured in `onCreate()`. In order to get `editText` width you can use `post`, `postDelayed`, `doOnPreDraw` (`onPreDrawListener`) or `viewTreeObserver`.

Comment: requestLayout() not working, can you provide an example code please.

Comment: @ISHANKALANSOORIYA, did you debug an application? What sizes did you get? I mean TextView width and RecyclerView width (before and after resizing)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856180/usage-of-forcelayout-requestlayout-and-invalidate. You can set RecyclerView width programmatically (for instance, layoutParams.width = 1000) and then call `testRecyclerView.requestLayout()`.

Comment: I did run some tests turns out recyclerView is getting the text length inside the editText as its width not the editText width

Comment: using post working for me, thank you very much

Comment: @ISHANKALANSOORIYA, glad to hear it! I also used `measure` this way: `someView.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`, but it works not always and depends on view size (in my case I used `android:layout_width="match_parent"`).